# How to get pixel color of an image without BufferedImage?

Tags: java

I am making a maze game where your mouse can't touch a certain color. The problem I am having is getting the pixel color without using a BufferedImage. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. Try to use `Robot` and `PointerInfo` declared as:

```
PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point coord = pointer.getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

And then to get a `Color` upon a `Point`:

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getY());
```